# How to escape in YAML the correct way?

Tags: escape-characters, yaml

On CentOS 7 I am using cloud-init to spin off a droplet using the DigitalOcean API which requires YAML formatting.

I got most parts working fine, but struggle on escaping the commands running at 'runcmd' below:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e     # Stop on first error

curl  -X POST https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer '$api_key'' \
-d '{
"name":"'$droplet_name'",
"region":"'$region'",
"size":"'$size'",
"image":"'$image'", 
"ssh_keys":'$root_ssh_pub_key',
"backups":false,
"ipv6":false,
"private_networking":false,
"user_data":"
    #cloud-config

    users:
    - name: SomeUser
      groups: wheel
      shell: /bin/bash
      ssh-authorized-keys:
              - ssh-dss AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDD...

    runcmd:
    - sed -i -e '$aAllowUsers SomeUser' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - sed -i -e '/PermitRootLogin/s/^.*$/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - service sshd restart
"}'
```

The errors I receive are:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: no
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 63
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the single quotes for for the `-d` commandline options both for specifying strings separated by `$variable` as well as for quoting the argument for the second `sed` command.

For `$aAllowUsers SomeUser` this might be what you want, but for `/PermitRootLogin/s/^.*$/PermitRootLogin no/` this is probably not what you want `/bin/sh` to expand. Putting backslashes in there should help:

```
   - sed -i -e \'/PermitRootLogin/s/^.*$/PermitRootLogin no/\' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

YAML should not have any problems with that list item having single quotes in the middle of the scalar value.

Comment: In my case I used sed's `c` espcaped like: `sed -i '/PermitRootLogin/c\\\PermitRootLogin without-password' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 3):

Use heredoc for such an input.  And you need to escape newlines and quotes because they are not allowed in your `appliaction/json` construct.

```
user_data=$(awk -v 'ORS=\\n' 1 <<'HERE' | sed 's/"/\\"/g'
#cloud-config

users:
- name: SomeUser
  groups: wheel
  shell: /bin/bash
  ssh-authorized-keys:
  - ssh-dss AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDD...

runcmd:
- sed -i -e '$aAllowUsers SomeUser' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- sed -i -e '/PermitRootLogin/s/^.*$/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- service sshd restart
HERE
)

curl -X POST https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $api_key" \
-d - <<HERE 
{
  "name": "$droplet_name",
  "region": "$region",
  "size": "$size",
  "image": "$image", 
  "ssh_keys": "$root_ssh_pub_key",
  "backups": false,
  "ipv6": false,
  "private_networking": false,
  "user_data": "$user_data"
}
HERE
```

Comment: You solution is pure gold.